How to structure large data in Firestore for multiple instances of Reactflow data
I am trying to determine the best way to structure data in firestore across multiple different Reactflow flow charts. The amount of nodes and edges could grow to become large (could be up to 10,000 or more) per flow. Each node can be 500 bytes so the nodes alone would grow beyond the 1mb capacity of a document. There are multiple designs I am considering but none seem straight forward. On the load of each flow I will need to pull in all the nodes and edges at initialization, but the nodeData only when viewing a specific node.
This would be all the data in one json
[
  "flow1": {
    "nodes": [{node info}, ...],
    "nodeData": [{internal node data}, ...]
    "edges": [{edge info}, ...],
    "otherArrays": [...],
    "metaData": {}
  },
  "flow2": {
    ...
  }
]

The 1st design is all subcollections like a json file. I think this one makes the most sense as I can get all the documents need easier but the layout seem weirds as it would just be a giant tree of data for each flow.

[
  "flow1": {
    "nodes": [{node info}, ...],             //subcollection
    "nodeData": [{internal node data}, ...]  //subcollection
    "edges": [{edge info}, ...],             //subcollection
    "otherArrays": [...],                    //subcollection
    ...metadata
  },
  "flow2": {
    "nodes": [{node info}, ...],             //subcollection
    "nodeData": [{internal node data}, ...]  //subcollection
    "edges": [{edge info}, ...],             //subcollection
    "otherArrays": [...],                    //subcollection
    ...metadata
  }
]

The 2nd is to have a collection of the flows with metadata about each flow and the have each doc in the other collections store that flow's id. This would require doing a where clause (flowId == "flow1") on for all the docs at once.
flow collection

[
  "flow1": {
    ...metadata
  },
  "flow2": {
    ...metadata
  }
]

nodes, edges, nodeData and otherArrays are all in their own top level collection
[
  "nodeId1": {
    "flowId": "flow1",
    ...data
  },
  "nodeId2": {
    "flowId": "flow2",
    ...data
  },
  ...
]


Or maybe it's best to have every flow in its own data base and have top level collection like design 1
Any of these solutions would work in practice, but it is still a lot of doc reading for just initalizing the app once.
If you have another idea that make more sense I would love to hear it.
